# Trying to convert a javascript button to a lightning component

Tags: javascript, salesforce-lightning

I cannot convert a java button using the converter

I tried to use the Lightning Experience Configuration Converter to convert a java button to a lightning Component (Full) yet everytime (I am live in Production), i get this error "We were unable to deploy some metadata to your org due a timeout" Since i can preview the component and the controller code I believe i can simply copy that to a sandbox and then push.

I am getting errors when creating the component (copied the code-Developer Console-New Lightning component) and I got other errors when creating the Controller - New-Apex Class..

I have inserted a images of the code supplied by the converter and the original (the component, the controller and the original)

It was meant to assign a unique order number to an inscription on click.

[image: Component]

[image: Controller]

[image: Original Java Button Code]

The controller

```html
({
    apexExecute : function(component, event, helper) {
        //Call Your Apex Controller Method.
        var action = component.get("c.updateOrderNumber");

        action.setParams({
            'inscriptionId': ''+component.get('v.sObjectInfo.Id')+''
        });

        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            console.log(state);
            
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                //after code
                if (''+component.get('v.sObjectInfo.Order_Number__c')+'' == '') {  var result = response.getReturnValue();
  window.location.reload(false);
} else   helper.showTextAlert(component, 'Order Number already Exist');

            } else {
                
            }

            
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },

    accept : function(component, event, helper) {
        $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
    }
})
```

The Component

```html
<aura:component controller="UpdateOrderNumberOnButtonClick" extends="c:LCC_GenericLightningComponent" >
    <aura:handler event="c:LCC_GenericApplicationEvent" action="{!c.apexExecute}"/>
    <aura:set attribute="partially" value="false"></aura:set>
    <aura:attribute name="showAlert" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="alertText" type="String"/>
    <aura:set attribute="isAdditionalObject" value="false"></aura:set>

    <div>
        <div class="slds-scrollable slds-p-around_medium slds-text-heading_small" id="modal-content-id-1">
            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showAlert}">
                <p class="slds-hyphenate">{!v.alertText}</p>
                <aura:set attribute="else">
                    <div style="height: 6.75rem;">
                        <div role="status" class="slds-spinner slds-spinner_large slds-spinner_brand">
                            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading</span>
                            <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
                            <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </aura:set>
            </aura:if>
            <br/>
        </div>
        <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
            <lightning:button class="slds-button_brand" onclick="{!c.accept}" label="Accept"/>
        </footer>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

The original Javascript button

```js
Here's your current JavaScript button code, to compare with our suggestion.
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/24.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/apex.js")} 
var orderNumber = '{!Inscription__c.Order_Number__c}'; 
if(orderNumber == ''){ 
var result= sforce.apex.execute("UpdateOrderNumberOnButtonClick", "updateOrderNumber", {inscriptionId:'{!Inscription__c.Id}'}); 
window.location.reload(false); 
} 
else 
alert('Order Number already Exist');
```

Comment: Please show code as text, not images

Comment: Also, this is Javascript, not Java. They are not the same

Comment: @OneCricketeer is this what you needed.. and thanks for the head up